# Table Width Issue with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have made two tables, one of which does not fill the full width of the parent div.
Does anyone have a clue what's wrong? You will find below the JS fiddle code:

https://jsfiddle.net/factorbased/cps3Loa2/6

The issue seems to involve this part but I don't understand how to fix it:

```html
<head>
<style>
table.ReturnsTable {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
.tr_grey{background-color:#C0C0C0;}
.setheight{min-height: 100px; overflow: hidden;}
#pies3 div{float:left;}
#pies4 div{float:left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="csvBar12" style="display: none;">
[wbcr_php_snippet id="972"]
</div> 

<div id="pies3" class="setheight" width="100%">
<div id="chartdiv3" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" ></div>
<div><table class="ReturnsTable" border="2"> 
  <tr class="tr_grey"><td>Performance Statistics</td>  <td>Portfolio</td> <td>Benchmark</td> <td>Difference</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>3-Month Return (%)</td> <td id="b0"></td> <td id="b1"></td><td  id="b2"></td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>1-Year Return (%)</td> <td id="b3"></td> <td id="b4"></td> <td id="b5"></td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>3-Year Return (%)</td> <td id="b6"></td> <td id="b7"></td><td id="b8"></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>5-Year Return (%)</td> <td id="b9"></td> <td id="b10"></td> <td id="b11"></td> </tr>       
        </table></div>
</div>
<div id="pies4" class="setheight" width="100%">
<div id="chartdiv4" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" ></div>
<div><table class="ReturnsTable" border="2"> 
  <tr class="tr_grey"><td>Risk Measurements</td>  <td>Portfolio</td> <td>Benchmark</td> <td>Difference</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Standard Deviation (%)</td> <td id="b12"></td> <td id="b13"></td><td id="b14" ></td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Maximum Drawdown (%)</td> <td id="b15" ></td> <td id="b16" ></td> <td id="b17"></td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>Sharpe Ratio</td> <td id="b18"></td> <td id="b19"></td><td id="b20"></td></tr>
  <tr> <td>Index Correlation</td> <td id="b21"></td> <td id="b22"></td> <td id="b23"></td> </tr>       
       </table></div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Set the width of the parent div to 100%, via `style="width: 100%"`. Without an explicit width, the `<div>` is only as wide as table it contains, which is the smallest it can be to fit the cell contents. https://jsfiddle.net/yvkgh01r/

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I confirm your solution works, been banging my head for too long over this. Thanks!

Comment: As a suggestion, the table could look better if you used `border-collapse: collapse;`. :)